# Twitter button not showing if initially hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I have a Twitter button on the page using the widget. The button renders as it should unless I place it into a hidden container.

I would like to place the share button into a hidden container that only shows when clicked. I have all of the functionality working, however the Twitter button will not show if placed into a hidden container.

Comment: Can't show a descendant of a hidden element (display:none). Sounds like a design problem. You can though if it is `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS tag `display: none` then remove the tag when you click the button and add the tag back whenever you are done sharing to Twitter.

Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="clickMe" value="Click Me" />
<img src="img/twitter.png" class="twitterPic hideMe" />
```

**CSS**

Assuming you have a separate style sheet.

```
.hideMe { display: none;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".clickMe").on("click", function () {
    $(".twitterPic").removeClass("hideMe");
});
```

Here are some links to the JQuery pages to add and remove classes:

https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

https://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: This doesn't work. If the element is hidden, it will not render on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

- place the container outside the viewport by setting its left or
  right property to sth like 5000px `.container {left:5000px;}`
- take off the `display:none` css
  rule that's causing the problem. This way the twitter code should be
  able to fire properly when the page loads
- then set the container's position by using
  the `offset()` function when the user clicks on the button. This way
  the container will show where you want it to